# How to wait for data to be fetched from database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to print data from a Firebase database into the android studio logcat.
I'm able to get and store data into a list but i cannot print the list in the logcat. I think it's because the array is printed before the data from the firebase is fetched. I'm not sure how to get it to print after the data from firebase is fetched.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
// Main activity

package com.imaginationcreators.bvnlibrary;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        Search search = new Search();

        search.setLocalDatabase();


        for(int i = 0; i < search.genre.size(); i++ ) {
            Log.d("String", search.genre.get(i));
        }


    }




}
```

---

```
package com.imaginationcreators.bvnlibrary;


import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Search {



    private ArrayList<Books> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();

    private int numberOfResults;
    private int childsAdded = 0;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    public ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<>();
 public Search()
    {
        Log.d("String", "afterdatabasesearchclass");
    }

 public void setLocalDatabase()
    {
        Log.d("String", "notworking");

        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    genre.add(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("pogo", databaseError.getDetails());
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase APIs are asynchronous, meaning they return immediately.  When you run the following code:

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(...)
```

addChildEventListener returns immediately, and the results of the query are delivered to your callback some time later.  You can access the snapshot only after the callback is invoked.  Your code is trying to access it before the results are ready because setLocalDatabase() returns immediately before the results are ready.

[Please read this blog](https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) to better understand why Firebase APIs are asynchronous, and what to expect.

Comment: So how would I make it wait for the results

Comment: You don't. You respond to the results in your callback. That's the correct way to deal an async API.  Please read that blog post to understand better.